# How to make two custom tableviews that works like a 2 rows uipickerview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I created a uiscrollview and add a uitableview as subview. I use this class to create two scrollivew each has added a tableview inside it. I want these 2 tableview works like uipickerview which has 2 rows in it. When I click a uitableviewcell on the left, the other tableview should reload it's data to match the selection. Just like a uipickerview, when click a item in row 0, row 1 updates it's data. I want to implement this functionality in tableview, the only difference is that i click the cell in tableview, not scroll item like uipickerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep reference of two tableViews, two seperate dataSource array. And when the mainTableView is selected, form the dataSource of the second tableView and reload it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1) //Main TableView
    {
         //Form the dataSource of the second tableView
         //You need to have a logic to form this array  
         //from the selected indexPath of main tableView
         self.secondDataSourceArray = ...
         [self.secondTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```